# Where to save an Image - android

Tags: android, image, save

I am developing Android application where users choose an icon image from a gallery. I need to save that image (bitmap), so I can use it when application is restarted.

Any simple example would be greatly appreciated.

Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Make use of the code below to save an image:

```
void saveImage() {

File myDir=new File("/sdcard/saved_images");
myDir.mkdirs();

String fname = "Image.jpg";
File file = new File (myDir, fname);
if (file.exists ()) file.delete (); 
try {
       FileOutputStream out = new FileOutputStream(file);
       finalBitmap.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.JPEG, 90, out);
       out.flush();
       out.close();
       final AlertDialog alertDialog = new AlertDialog.Builder(this).create();  
            alertDialog.setTitle("Save");  
            alertDialog.setMessage("Your drawing had been saved:)");  
            alertDialog.setButton("OK", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {  
            public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) { 
                return;  
            }  
        });  
        alertDialog.show();
} catch (Exception e) {
       e.printStackTrace();
}
}
```

And to retrive image from sdcard:

Supose you retrieves the image from sdcard in your Import.java Acitivty like that:

```
File file = new File(getExternalFilesDir(null), "MyFile.jpg");
```

So, once you have your image in a File object, you just need to put its path on a Intent that will be used to be a result data, which will be sent back to the "caller" activity. In some point of your "called" acitivity you should do that:

```
Intent resultData = new Intent();
resultData.putExtra("imagePath", file.getAbsolutePath());
setResult(RESULT_OK,returnIntent);     
finish();
```

Your method onActivityResult:

```
@Override
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
  // TODO Auto-generated method stub
  super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);

  if(requestCode==RESULT_OK)
  {
    String path = data.getStringExtra("imagePath");           
  }
}
```

That's it!
Hope it helps :)

Comment: Problem with this approach is that image is not packed with app. What if user deletes the image stored in sdcard?

Comment: Yea thats a possibility

Comment: Thanks, that is what i need, i just use internal storage (`getFilesDir()`) instead of external...

Answer (score 0):

http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/data/data-storage.html

I would suggest using external storage

Answer (score 0):

Use `SharedPreferences` to store image in `Base64` String representation.

```
Bitmap imageBitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeStream(stream);
ByteArrayOutputStream byteArrayOutputStream = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
imageBitmap.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.JPEG, 100, byteArrayOutputStream );   
byte[] byte = byteArrayOutputStream.toByteArray(); 
String encodedImage = Base64.encodeToString(byte , Base64.DEFAULT);

SharedPreferences sharedPreferences = getSharedPreferences("SharedPreferencesName", <Mode>);
SharedPreferences.Editor sharedPreferencesEditor = sharedPreferences .edit();
sharedPreferencesEditor.putString("image_data", encodedImage).commit();
```

While retrieving, convert `Base64` representation back to `Bitmap`.

```
SharedPreferences sharedPreferences = getSharedPreferences("SharedPreferencesName", <Mode>);
String encodedImage = sharedPreferences.getString("image_data", "");

if( !encodedImage.equals("") ){
    byte[] byte = Base64.decode(encodedImage , Base64.DEFAULT);
    Bitmap bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeByteArray(byte, 0, byte.length);
    imageView.setImageBitmap(bitmap);    
}
```